# PHP array doubling digits

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array and I want to double it but after executing the array doesn't change how to correct it as minimally as possible.

```
<?php
   $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   foreach ($arr as $value) {
     $value = $value * 2;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values didn't double because you're not saying the **key** should be overwritten in `$arr` this code should be working:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  $arr[$key] = $value*2;
}
```

An alternative would be to use `array_map()`.

```
<?php

 function double($i){
   return $i*2;
 }  

 $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
 $arr = array_map('double', $arr);

 var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Comment: And what was OP's original problem ?

Comment: @Rizier123 That the values didn't double. They do with my script (alternative).

Comment: Yes, but *why* didn't the values double in OP's code?

Comment: OP also could simply just loop through by reference: `foreach ($arr as &$value)`

Comment: I think I then missed that one, that this gets deprecated, do you have the rfc link for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double the actual array `$arr` element, not just the value in the cycle.

```
<?php
   $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
     $arr[$key] = $value * 2;
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a variable $value which is assigning in each for loop so this value stored in $value is overwrithing in your foreach loop. You have

```
<?php
   $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   foreach ($arr as $value) {
     $value = $value * 2;
   }
?>
```

This will work

```
<?php
   $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   foreach ($arr as &$value) {
     $value = $value * 2;
   }

   print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

short solution, and supported in `< PHP 5.3`, try this code

```
<?php 
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr = array_map(create_function('$v', 'return $v * 2;'), $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/367750)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
   $arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
   array_walk($arr, function(&$item){ 
       $item*=2; 
   });
   var_dump($arr);
```